# Simulate low memory on real android device

Tags: android, performance, debugging, memory, android-appwidget

I have a problem with app widgets on Android **KitKat** 4.4.2, which is the OS removes my background running service without restarting it, although it's in sticky mode.

Now I found a trick to use **onTaskRemoved** to restart my service in case of low memory conditions.

But the problem is now how to simulate low memory condition on my device, not on emulator?

Comment: You could try loading a large array of empty `Double` objects? Keep adding objects to the list until you run out of memory.

Comment: People are always posting on SO about running out of memory processing bitmaps.  Maybe you can take some pictures using the camera and load them in your app.  Or just download some from the internet.

Comment: @Ricardo I tested this method, android memory manager sends such app to cache, because it's not "live"!

Comment: @AVEbrahimi Maybe it can work if you acquire a wake lock?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a native C code to do that. Here's what I would do:

1. Write a C code that allocates a large buffer, sleeps a number of seconds, computes a checksum on the buffer and then exits.
2. Compile the program on a Linux machine using "-static" compile flag. Android and Linux are binary compatible but you need the libc embedded into your binary to get rid of potential issues.
3. Copy the binary with adb on the device.
4. Run the binary.

At this point you have a native process that uses an amount of memory equal to the size of the buffer you allocated. I don't think this process would be put to sleep even if you perform other tasks on the device, so it's memory usage will simulate a "low memory" situation.